# creating login form and connecting to database in wordpress

Tags: database, wordpress

I'm working on migrating a joomla website to wordpress and i've come across a problem with the login/users/database. How can i make a login form ( in the header for example) and then "connect" this form to the database i have (SQL)?

Comment: If you mean log in as a WordPress user, check out the [wp_login_form](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_login_form) function.  If you don't mean logging in as a WordPress user, what do you mean?

Comment: @Hobo i mean a random user login in (whose data is in the database)